# WebRTC Audio in electron

Tags: electron, webrtc

I'm making a desktop app using electron and want to build a voice chat inside the app, i understand that WebRTC is the principal solution for this, in my research i read about Assignaling, Stun and Turn server's. But my realy question is, if i have a client using Electron, can i made the app send streaming voice from microphone to a Server(Elixir, python or Node) and the server just broadcast for everyone in the room ? or a just need the signaling, Stun and Turn ?

If someone have a tip in material where i can learn about the solution i realy grateful.

Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can use webRTC just as you would in the Browser. I tryed to develop a voice chat using peerJS and socket.io, but It seems like if there is a problem with electron that prevents voice connections outside of your network. For one-to-many-broadcasting you can use mediaSoup, for example. More information can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jpopesculian/a19bd79481000e12dc9d).

If you manage to get webRTC media streams working somehow, I'd be happy if you let me know