# Node.JS Voice over IP Electron

Tags: node.js, electron, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I am fairly new to Node.JS, but I want to code a Voice Chat Program which uses the Electron Framework for the Client.
The Server shall be hosted on a Linux Computer. I want to connect with multiple Clients to this Server and talk and recieve audio from others connected. I want this as a Project so me and my buddies can talk over a piece of software I made.
As I pretty much don't know much about Streams in NodeJS. Which protocolls can I use, for best quality and low network bandwith.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63331485/webrtc-audio-in-electron). For more infos just reply.